# Disable element for different product ID's if customfield has duplicate value

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, virtuemart

I need some help with the following issue. I'll give the whole scenario. It shouldn't be too much work, but I just can not get it to work 100%.

All my products are loaded in the category page. Now, I have a customfield "Sequence No."(virtuemart__custom_id = 2).  Let's say the other customfield is "Score" (virtuemart_custom_id = 3), and the value can be any integer value.

**Different products can have the same sequence number.**

So let's assume we have this scenario:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Seq #</th>
<th>Product</th>
<th>Score</th>
<th>Cart Button</th>
</tr>

<?php foreach ($product->virtuemart_product_id){
<tr>
<td>123456</td>
<td>Shoes</td>
<td>50</td>
<td>"Addtocart-button"</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>123456</td>
<td>Shirt</td>
<td>55</td>
<td>"Addtocart-button"</td>
</tr> // THE CODE BELOW SHOULD BE HERE, I just seperated it to make it easier to understand.
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

So, I need to disable the "Addtocart-button" **for the product with the higher score;** in this case, the "Shirt" product.

Here is the code I wrote. It is inside the **"foreach ($this->product as $products) { }"** element:

```
<?php 
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$sequence = "SELECT customfield_value FROM `jos_virtuemart_product_customfields` WHERE virtuemart_custom_id=2";
$score = "SELECT customfield_value FROM `jos_virtuemart_product_customfields` WHERE virtuemart_custom_id=3";
$producttest = "SELECT virtuemart_product_id FROM `jos_virtuemart_product_customfields`";


if($sequence==$sequence && $score>=$score){ ?>
  <script>
   jQuery(".addtocart-button").css("display", "none");
  </script>
<?php } } ?>
```

Is there any way to check for duplicates in a column in the database? I'd need to check customfield_value of "Sequence Number" for every "Product ID". I then need to determine which of the duplicate values has the highest "Score".

The final outcome would be that the "addtocart-button" is disabled for the product with the higher score, **IF** the sequence number is the same and virtuemart_product_id is different.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that currently it is disabling the addtocart-button, but for every single product that is loaded. It should only be for the ones where the sequence number is a duplicate and the one with the highest score.

Comment: Okay, so I took your values above and inserted them into a [sqlfiddle][1]. I added one extra result to show how products can be ordered. This is not the solution, but it will get you closer to your answer. I have a single query which returns all your products with an extra column which has a count of duplicates. I did a GROUP BY seq, score. So the first one for each seq is the one you want to make your button active, and using your count you can disable the button on other products inside your jQuery script


  [1]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7eb0d/2

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply mcv! I appreciate it. Will try your code and give it a go!

Comment: What is the "p1" and "p2" referring to?

Comment: p1 and p2 are just aliases for a table. In this scenario I referenced the same table twice, so it was ideal. I am also comparing 2 instances of the same table to determine the count for each seq, so using aliases is required or the query would not know which table to reference for what values. Here is more on that topic: [https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp]